# Is there an alternative extension to 'Python Preview' in Vs code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Some time ago I used 'Python preview' in Vs Code.
Now this extension is 'Deprecated', but is there an alternative that does the same things, even graphically?

Comment: just use the debugger, it has the same functionality, or write a new version of the extension, where does it say it is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can try to use **debug**. It is similar to Python preview in displaying variables, but lacks graphical function. There is no support for graphic function at present.

Comment: thanks a lot! I use now debug for vs code :-)